# Is there a better way to display an Excel spreadsheet inside a form?

Tags: vb.net

I want to display some Excel sheets in a form.  If a workbook has multiple sheets, I want to display them all individually.  Ideally, I'd like the entire sheet to be visible(i.e. custom zoom for each sheet).

This is what I'm currently doing, but golly is it slow and ugly.  What the code below does is grabs the individual sheets in a workbook, and save each sheet as PDFs.

Then in a separate, uninteresting, block of code I grab those PDFs and display them in a webbrowser control on the form.  (Why not the PDF control you ask?  *shrug*  I don't like the way that control looks or works for what I'm doing.  This is only meant to be a display of the Excel sheet, not an interactive file.)

```
 Private Sub GetExcelWorksheets(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal OutputName As String, Optional ByVal pWord As String = "")
        Dim CellValue As String = ""
        If IO.File.Exists(FileName) Then
            Dim Proceed As Boolean = False
            Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
            Dim xlWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
            Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
            Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
            Dim xlWorkSheets As Excel.Sheets = Nothing
            Dim xlCells As Excel.Range = Nothing
            xlApp = New Excel.Application
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
            xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
            If pWord <> "" Then
                xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(FileName, UpdateLinks:=2, [ReadOnly]:=True, Password:=pWord)
            Else
                xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(FileName, UpdateLinks:=2, [ReadOnly]:=True)
            End If
            xlApp.Visible = False
            xlWorkSheets = xlWorkBook.Sheets
            Dim sheetCount = 0
            For x As Integer = 1 To xlWorkSheets.Count
                xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkSheets(x), Excel.Worksheet)
                xlWorkSheets(x).activate
                xlWorkSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, savePath & OutputName & x & ".pdf", Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, False, False, 1, 1, False)
                sheetCount = sheetCount + 1
            Next

            xlWorkBook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
            xlApp.UserControl = True
            xlApp.Quit()
            ReleaseComObject(xlCells)
            ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheets)
            ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet)
            ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook)
            ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBooks)
            ReleaseComObject(xlApp)


            Dim frm As New StampingAndon.frmMain
            frm.DisplayOnMainForm(sheetCount)
            'DisplayOnMainForm(sheetCount)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("'" & FileName & "' not located.")
        End If
    End Sub
```

So, this actually works, but it takes a significant amount of time to process the Excel file and "print" it to PDF.  I'd like to increase the efficiency if I can.  Ideally I'd also like to put the sheet "image" into a PictureBox control as that has the auto-zoom, but I can live with some scroll bars if I have to.

Comment: Maybe reading the data from the Excel file using a standard OleDbConnecton and presenting it in a DataGridView? So you get read of the Interop stuff and speed up the whole process.

Comment: If it was just numbers and such, I'd agree (I've done that before), but this has images inserted into the Excel sheet which doesn't work out right.

Comment: I understand. This informaton should be in the question. Try with [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus).

Comment: Have you seen [How to use the WebBrowser control to open Office documents in Visual C# 2005 or in Visual C# .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/webbrowser-open-office-document-in-visual-c)?

Comment: @RobertBaron I did try that, but it's not working out for me.  The basic tutorial in the link you added is throwing lots of errors that I'm not experienced enough to decipher.  (e.g. "namespace 'AxWebBrowser' could not be found", "The type <type> exists in both 'AxInterop.SHDocVw' and 'AxSHDocVW'" (multiple of those)).  I do appreciate the effort, but I may just have to release a p.o.s. here.

Comment: There is the `Range.CopyPicture` function that probably would be faster.  However that requires using the Clipboard and only works well with EnhancedMetaFile format that the WinForm Clipboard does not retrieve (you have to roll your own Clipboard retrieval via the Clipboard API).  Is a commercial product (i.e. SpreadsheetGear) solution not viable?

Comment: @TnTinMn We're a small, under educated, and under budgeted IT department.  If I can't make it myself, we're probably not going to get it.  I will look into that Range.CopyPicture.... That actually sounds promising. Thanks.

Comment: @gCanuck, if you run in to problems trying to implement `Range.CopyPicture`, post back here and I'll try to cobble together an example.